# java.io.filenotfound android exception on web service call

Tags: android, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I am getting exception `java.io.filenotfound` android exception on web service call in android.But when I run the same `url` in my browser it works fine.I am communication with the project running on local host in visual studio. My `url` is like this:

```
http://10.0.2.2:7378/HighriseeSite/appservices.svc/savewc?WcID=3646&WODetailID=480982&PSID=2084&wcdate=07/14/2015 &wcompleted=1&remarks=&rabill=0&connectivityID=0&length=0&breadth=0&height=0&execby=0
```

When I use the same `url` in my browser by replacing 10.0.2.2 with the `localhost` it works fine `webservice` gets called.But when the same `url` is called from the android studio project I get the exception:

```
java.io.filenotfound
```

and in the visual studio where project is running and from where the `webservice` is being called I get the exception as:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But the same `url` works fine in the browser.I am not able to detect what is wrong with this.Any kind of help will be appreciated.

My code for accessing webservice is like this:

```
 for( WCompletionData Itm:lstWC)
                {

                     if(Float.parseFloat (Itm.getCompQty())>0.0)
                     {

                         ur = "http://" + ServerDetails.hostServer + "/appservices.svc/savewc?WcID=" + Itm.getWO_No().trim() + "&WODetailID=" + Itm.getWODetail_Id().trim() + "&PSID=" + Itm.getPS_Id().trim() + "&wcdate=" + currentDateTimeString.trim().trim() + " &wcompleted=" + Itm.getCompQty().trim() + "&remarks=&rabill=" + Itm.getRABill_Id().trim() + "&connectivityID=0&length=0&breadth=0&height=0&execby=0";
                         //String ur = "http://"+ServerDetails.hostServer+"/appservices.svc/TaskQuanityList?MaterialID="+MatrID+"&ProjectNo="+ProID+"&TaskNo="+TaskID;


                         Log.d("URLgggrn", ur);


                         // Replace it with your own WCF service path
                         URL json = new URL(ur);
                         URLConnection jc = json.openConnection();
                         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));


                         line = reader.readLine().toString();



                         Log.d("Line", line);
                         WCNo = WCNo + line + ",";



                     }
```

I am using same code on another activity and it works fine on that activity.

Comment: Why this question is being down rated? if you dont like question please comment I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: Use in browser with same IP, if it works then post code.

Comment: HI, Can you show what youve done in your code

Answer (score 0):

> To get rid of File Not Found Exception while requesting to a URL
>   from android we should avoid white space from URL. If you need to pass
>   parameter data which contain space you have to use below code

```
String param1 = "happy coding";
String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(param1 , "UTF-8");
```